# trouble in update From mac OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6 ----TO---- > macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: macos-sierra, osx-elcapitan

i have question that in my mac currently i am having mac OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6 and now i want to update it with mac Download macOS Sierra 10.12.6

now, i have .dmg file of macOS Sierra 10.12.6 but when i am going to download it gives me error that

[image: error message]

now i find a lot .dmg of version 10.12 but i didn't get anywhere then i got version 10.12.1

now i am confuse that do i compulsory need to fine 10.12 and install it and than after update 10.12.4 and than after 10.12.6 ?

pls provide me detail information about it.

Thanks For your precise support.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please delete from here and consider posting at https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @rmaddy hey i am here to get knowledge of everything..if u have lots of knowledge and don't wanna share than let it go but don't demotivation others. Thanks :(

Comment: I'm not demotivating anyone. Stack overflow is specifically for posting programming questions. Issues updating macOS is not a programming question. I helpfully pointed this out to you and even suggested the proper place for your question.

Comment: @rmaddy okay sir.... i understand and Thank you very much :)  but pls remove ur down vote now....

Comment: Don't assume it is my down vote. But why should the down vote be removed? Your question is completely off topic and it should be removed. You should click the delete link just below your question.

Comment: OP has now posted the question at Apple.SE https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304075/how-to-upgrade-from-os-x-el-capitan-10-11-6-to-macos-sierra-10-12-6

Comment: @grgarside And why aren't people voting to close this? Why hasn't the OP deleted it?

Comment: Thanks for caring me guys @grgarside... ;)

Comment: Thanks for caring me guys @rmaddy... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after so many confusion and question i find the correct answer.

this is the answer only for who are confuse and i am trying to draft this message for whom who is truely required.

now, answer is

If you have mac OS X El Capitan than
GOTO > AppStore > download & update : https://developer.apple.com/macos/

now after update your os

you can update your xcode from below link

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12

Thank you friends..